# Optimize a search results query with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2012

I rewrote a search functionality in a website that used to make around 13 roundtrips to the database server to build the results page. What I basically did was put together all these 13 queries into a single big string and instead of sending 13 roundtrips to the db, now I send just 1 and then I handle the multiple result set returned.

This big query consists basically of a main select

```
select 
    column1, column2, column3 
from
    ...
inner join 
    ... 
order by
    ..... fetch offset etc
```

for pagination and the 12 others uses the first one as a subquery without the pagination part to build some filter boxes to help the user narrow the results (just like the amazon search results).

This is working.

The problem is that I have that feeling that this is not right. That this could be more efficient. I'm not a DBA or an expert SQL Server coder and it's pretty clear that the same query being repeated 13 times doesn't seem right.

Would SQL Server be smart enough to optimize it without any change made by me?

A friend of mine has suggested that I use a table variable and insert all the rows in it, then I use it to get the data used by the "filter boxes" and use this same variable to return the data paginated. But the default page size is just 20, what if I have 10000 items? Would that be efficient?

I'm assuming that just 1 round trip is more efficient. Maybe split in 2 then?

Any tip would be very appreciated!

Comment: It'd be much clearer if you posted a representation of your big query. SQL Server will certainly cache and reuse results in RAM where possible. I think you should extend your "feeling this is not right" to. "Will this still work in 6 months when I have 1,000 x more records"

Comment: if I substitute a huge truck instead of 13 small vans will it be faster and cheaper? (this is similar to what you just asked us) i.e. Right now your question has no definitive answer due to lack of facts.

Comment: I`m having trouble to run the project now and get the exact query it generates, but as I said, it creates a dynamically SELECT query and then reuses it 12 more times in the following template:

SELECT {1} AS Id, {2} AS Name, COUNT({1}) AS Total FROM (
{0}
) AS T
GROUP BY {1}, {2}

in the place of {0}

Comment: Would u plz provide table schema and ur exact query ??